# Using TRIM in QUERY Match

Tags: sql, regex, google-sheets

This is driving me nuts so I beg for assistance!

I have this query

```
"Select A, B where UPPER(H) matches
    '.*(?:^|,|,\s)"&REGEXEXTRACT(Q3,"^[^[{]+")&"(?:,\s|,|$).*' limit 1",0)
```

But I need to change the match so that ignore spaces. Ideally I would just wrap Q3 in a `trim` but don't think I can do that.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

A `[^[{]` pattern matches any char but `[` and `{` and thus also matches whitespace.

You may match any amount of whitespaces at the start, then capture any amount of chars other than `[`, `{`, and then match a char other than `[`, `{` or whitespace:

```
=REGEXEXTRACT(B40,"^\s*([^[{]*[^[{\s])")
```

**Details**

- `^` - start of string
- `\s*` - 0+ whitespaces
- `([^[{]*[^[{\s])` - Group 1:

  - `[^[{]*` - 0+ chars other than `[` and `{`
  - `[^[{\s]` - a single char other than `[`, `{` and whitespace.